# Prove a map of tensor product is linear.

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Let $L, M, K$ are vector spaces over $F$. I try to prove the map

$$\tau: (L \otimes M) \times N \rightarrow L \otimes(M \otimes N)$$ defined by $$\tau(\alpha\otimes \beta, \gamma)=\alpha\otimes (\beta \otimes \gamma)$$ is a linear map w.r.t variable $\alpha \otimes \beta$.

Please give me a idea. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You first ought to show it is well defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted in the comments, you'll get this for free with a construction of $\tau$ that ensures it is actually well-defined. Not every tensor in $L\otimes M$ is decomposable in the form $\alpha\otimes\beta$, so the "definition" you gave is insufficient.

Consider $f:L\times M\times N\to L\otimes(M\otimes N)$ defined by
$$f(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=\alpha\otimes(\beta\otimes\gamma)$$
Clearly $f$ is trilinear since the tensor products are bilinear. For each fixed $\gamma\in N$, the map $f(-,-,\gamma)$ is blinear on $L\times M$, so by the universal property of $L\otimes M$ there is a unique *linear* map $\tau_{\gamma}:L\otimes M\to L\otimes(M\otimes N)$ satisfying
$$f(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=\tau_{\gamma}(\alpha\otimes\beta)$$
Now we can define $\tau:(L\otimes M)\times N\to L\otimes(M\otimes N)$ by
$$\tau(x,\gamma)=\tau_{\gamma}(x)$$
which in particular satisfies
$$\tau(\alpha\otimes\beta,\gamma)=\tau_{\gamma}(\alpha\otimes\beta)=f(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=\alpha\otimes(\beta\otimes\gamma)$$
and is linear in $x$ by linearity of each $\tau_{\gamma}$.

In fact, since $\tau_{\gamma}$ also depends linearly on $\gamma$, $\tau$ is *bilinear* and therefore induces a linear map $(L\otimes M)\otimes N\to L\otimes(M\otimes N)$ satisfying
$$(\alpha\otimes\beta)\otimes\gamma\mapsto\alpha\otimes(\beta\otimes\gamma)$$
which is an "associativity" isomorphism.

Comment: I sincerely thank you and your reply. It helped me to understand my problem clearly.